# Add/Remove element from an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write 2 functions in C, one of which would add an element to the end of my array that i pass as an argument, and the other function which would delete an element from the array passed as an argument.

I am not really familiar with C, and not good into pointers arithmetic.

I have tried with something like this, but it seems not to be working properly:

```
void remove_element(type *elements, type element, int size){
    int i;
    int index = 0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i+=1){
        if(equals(elements[i], element)) index = i;
    }

    for(i=index; i<size-1; i+=1){
        elements[i] = elements[i+1];
    }
}


void add_element(type *elements, type element, int size){
    elements = realloc(elements, size*sizeof(element));
    elements[size-1] = element;
}
```

That is how I want to call the functions:

```
add_element(elements, new_element, size);
remove_element(elements, element_to_remove, size);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *how* it's not working properly? You might also want to show some code showing how you use these functions, please read e.g. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it actually puts anything into the array.

Comment: Describe *"it seems not to be working properly"*.  What input did you give your program?  What results did you expect? what results did you actually get?  I only see two functions in your code.  No `main`, no input, no output of any kind.

Comment: Your `add_element()` function allocates a new array, but it never returns it to the caller.

Comment: @Barmar It was a typo, i edited it now... I want to pass an array, and then let the function to take care of adding/removing element into/from it.

Comment: It still doesn't return the new value of `elements` to the caller, so they'll keep on using the old array, which has been freed.

Comment: @Barmar I want to edit the array by reference. Not to return the new array, but only to change the original array. Thats what i am asking on how to do

Comment: Calling `realloc()` every time you add an element seems like very poor design.  You should use a structure that keeps track of the allocated size and the number of elements that are in use, and only reallocate when you need to go past the size.

Comment: But you're not changing the original array. `realloc()` returns a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses two lines may cause *undefined behavior*:

```
cvorovi = realloc(elements, size*sizeof(element));
elements[size-1] = cv;
```

The `realloc` function is not guaranteed to return a pointer to the same area you want to reallocate, meaning that `elements` may not point to the allocated area after the call. You **must** use the returned pointer.

This will most likely cause problems with the code *calling* this function, as that code will not know anything about the change of the pointers. Either pass `elements` by reference (i.e. a pointer to pointer) or return the new pointer.

Also, after seeing your edit, you *do* remember to pass in a larger size than the current size when you call `add_element`? Otherwise it will just reallocate the same size over and over again, and overwriting the last inserted element each call. You may want to consider making a structure keeping track of these, and and special set of functions that takes this structure as argument and handles all the things (like keeping track of the size) internally.

Comment: Actually this line looks like this:
elements = realloc(elements, size*sizeof(element));

The original line was a typo.

Comment: @Whizzil But the last part of the answer is still valid. How will the calling code know about the possible change?

Comment: I would appreciate a solution, an actual code of how it would work what i want, it would be much clearer that way.
@edit: yes i do remember that :)

Comment: @Whizzil Just return the new pointer from `add_element`, and assign that in the caller. Like `elements = add_element(elements, new_element, size + 1);`